# performance when creating UI both with storyboards and in code

Tags: ios, performance, storyboard

Storyboard can be an extremely convenient way of creating UI, but it doesn't give you the freedom code does. Therefore I am using storyboards, but create much of my interface in code in `viewDidLoad:`

I wonder if there are any performance penalties when creating an UI with storyboards and also in code? Such as long app launch times..

Comment: No, there shouldn't be an appreciable difference either way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pros and cons of using XIBs and doing views programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332998/pros-and-cons-of-using-xibs-and-doing-views-programmatically)