# Are storyboards affect performance at runtime in comparison to programmatic layout?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I know that using storyboards increase compile time. But does it affect runtime speed in any way in comparison to create programmatic layout?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which is more efficient way? StoryBoard or XIB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22524232/which-is-more-efficient-way-storyboard-or-xib)

Comment: Please see other https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35841150/performance-when-creating-ui-both-with-storyboards-and-in-code

Comment: @MaxMacLeod No, my question is about the runtime performance

Comment: See linked questions "cell cannot be reuse”, " long app launch times”, "any performance penalties”. All relate to runtime. 

Storyboards have been around for about a decade since iOS 5 back in 2012. A quick Stackoverflow or online search will reveal a multitude of resources over the years.

Comment: @MaxMacLeod "cell cannot be reuse” is not kind of related to my question. And "performance penalties", "long app launch times” were mentioned in question, but there was not a straight answer. I was asked this during the interview, so I'm wondering for that